# Display cursor movement while running e2e test cases using protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

I am completely new to e2e testing using protractor. 
My question is, How to display/show cursor movement when I run my test cases. I have searched in google, I didn't get any result. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it by injecting a module with [`addMockModule`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.addMockModule) that tracks the mouse events and creates temporary fixed dots at the coordinates of the event:

In the [`protractor.conf`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L190) file

```
 onPrepare: function() {

    // track mouse movements
    var trackMouse = function() {

      angular.module('trackMouse', []).run(function($document) {

        function addDot(ev) {

          var color = 'black',
            size = 6;

          switch (ev.type) {
            case 'click':
              color = 'red';
              break;
            case 'dblclick':
              color = 'blue';
              break;
            case 'mousemove':
              color = 'green';
              break;
          }

          var dotEl = $('<div></div>')
            .css({
              position: 'fixed',
              height: size + 'px',
              width: size + 'px',
              'background-color': color,
              top: ev.clientY,
              left: ev.clientX,

              'z-index': 9999,

              // make sure this dot won't interfere with the mouse events of other elements
              'pointer-events': 'none'
            })
            .appendTo('body');

          setTimeout(function() {
            dotEl.remove();
          }, 1000)

        }

        $document.on({
          click: addDot,
          dblclick: addDot,
          mousemove: addDot
        });

      });

    };
    browser.addMockModule('trackMouse', trackMouse);

  },
```